# Allow access to files in folder only from specific (other) domain

Tags: file, .htaccess, cross-domain

I have a folder at destination.com/foldername. I want to make the files in this folder ONLY accessible using links in my other website on a different domain (example.com). It's also NOT allowed to acces the files directly.
I have read some posts about this, and I think it can be done using a htaccess file in destination.com/foldername. But, I don't know what lines I need to add to this file. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

To make files accessible only from a referer domain you can use the following in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on


#If the referer domain not example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !example\.com [NC]
#and the request is for an existent file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
#forbid this request
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```